# VBA button for inserting cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

can someone help. I need vba code for button that insert blank rows (but not entire row) only in columns A->E.
So new row is added based on Column E. If for example row(5) <> row(6) then insert blank row between them.

Sorry if i ask too much, i am not familiar with vba, but this would help me with my job sooo much.

[This is my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATrV3.jpg)

[This is what i need to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WozVF.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Sub shift_cells()
Dim i As Integer
For i = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 5).Value <> Cells(i, 5).Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 5)).Insert shift:=xlDown
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you soooo much :D

Answer (score 0):

**:Caveat:**

*Since Column D & E having duplicate, therefore for proper results I've used Column A to compare values & insert blank row, since has unique IDs.*

- In fact a blank row is required to be inserted (*check the attached screen shot*), if & when previous value is not similar to current.

---

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
     Dim iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer
     Dim oRng As Range
    
     Set oRng = Range("A2")
    
     iRow = oRng.Row
     iCol = oRng.Column
    
     Do
    
     If Cells(iRow + 1, iCol) <> Cells(iRow, iCol) Then
        Cells(iRow + 1, iCol).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
        iRow = iRow + 2
     Else
        iRow = iRow + 1
     End If
    
     Loop While Not Cells(iRow, iCol).Text = ""
    
    End Sub
```

---

**N.B.**

- In above code `Range("A2")` is editable.
- Save the WB as Macro enable `*.xlsm`.